# open source license use vs reproduction vs distribution

Tags: open-source, apache-license

I was looking at the Apache license, and under "4. Redistribution" I have to meet a few conditions in order to "reproduce and distribute."

What if I simply just want to copy and paste some code into my website/app? Is that considered "reproduce and distribute?" Would I still have to do all those things listed under "4. Redistribution" section?

Answer (score 1):

IANAL, but copy paste coding probably puts you at least in the area of a derivative work. Even rewriting a section of code under the "influence" of the open source code can make your work a derivative work.  You would have to fulfill those conditions listed in section 4.

Comment: So copy and paste code is considered "reproduce and distribute?"

Comment: "Redistribution. You may reproduce and distribute copies of the Work or Derivative Works..." yours would be a derivative work, so yes, you would be considered to be "reproducing/distributing*

Comment: Copy and paste is considered "creating a derivative work", which means the GPL rules apply to you. It has nothing to do with reproduction or distribution, that is a completely different matter.

Comment: @gnasher729 so you saying I am "creating a derivative work" BUT NOT "reproducing/distributing?" And the other comment responded to me is wrong?

Comment: The copy/paste creates the derivative work. Once it's on your website and gets delivered to users, that's when it is reproduced or distributed. These are two completely different things.